# use of timer in activiti to complete task within a specified time

Tags: timer, activiti

I create a workflow in which i am using timer i.e. i want to use timer in a user task. It means that if a user does not perform his task in the specified time then the task got clear from his pending task list and the token move to the specified node in the workflow. 
My bmpn.xml file is:

```
    <process id="newprocess6" isExecutable="true">
    <startEvent id="start" name="Start Consulting" activiti:initiator="initiator">
    <extensionElements>
    <activiti:formProperty id="hname" name="Hospital Name" type="string">    </activiti:formProperty>
    <activiti:formProperty id="dname" name="Doctor Name" type="string">    </activiti:formProperty>
    </extensionElements>
    </startEvent>
    <userTask id="usertask1" name="Start Consulting with seema" activiti:assignee="seema">
    <extensionElements>
    <activiti:formProperty id="consult" name="consult" type="enum">
    <activiti:value id="true" name="true"></activiti:value>
    <activiti:value id="false" name="false"></activiti:value>      </activiti:formProperty>
    </extensionElements>
    </userTask>
    <endEvent id="end1"></endEvent>
    <boundaryEvent id="timer2" attachedToRef="usertask1" cancelActivity="true">
    <timerEventDefinition>
    <timeDuration>PT2M</timeDuration>
    </timerEventDefinition>
</boundaryEvent>
<userTask id="usertask2" name="Start Consulting with saurabh" activiti:assignee="saurabh">
<extensionElements>
<activiti:formProperty id="consult" name="consult" type="enum">
<activiti:value id="true" name="true"></activiti:value>
<activiti:value id="false" name="false"></activiti:value>
</activiti:formProperty>
</extensionElements>
</userTask>
<endEvent id="end2"></endEvent>
<sequenceFlow id="flow1" sourceRef="start" targetRef="usertask1"></sequenceFlow>
<sequenceFlow id="flow2" sourceRef="usertask1" targetRef="end1"></sequenceFlow>
<sequenceFlow id="flow4" sourceRef="usertask2" targetRef="end2"></sequenceFlow>
<sequenceFlow id="flow3" sourceRef="timer2" targetRef="usertask2"></sequenceFlow>
</process>
```

according to my knowledge, If user seema is not completing her task within 2 minutes then the task will clear from seema's pending task list and should be move to user saurabh's pending task list. But the task is not moving to saurabh's pending task list.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look in the Activiti documentation: http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#timerEventDefinitions

> timeDuration. To specify how long the timer should run before it is
>   fired, a timeDuration can be specified as sub-element of
>   timerEventDefinition. The format used is the ISO 8601 format (as
>   required by the BPMN 2.0 specification). Example (interval lasting 10
>   days): P10D

As soon as your User Task has started, this specified time duration gets executed. When this time is over, your timer boundary event gets fired and you can move to the next User Task

Comment: I don't want to use specific date and time. I want that when task is assigned to a user then the timer will start and if the user did not complete his task in specified time then token move to another node specified in the workflow.

Comment: Ben's answer is correct, the first event that occurs when a human task is reached is the "assign" event (refer here for why : http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#taskListeners) therefore, the duration you define in the boundary timer event will be accurate. If you need more complex logic, then use a TaskListener to manipulate the attached timer.

Comment: I used PT5M...now timer is firing but not at the correct time...I defined time for 5 minutes but the task is deleted from usertask1 in 10-15 seconds and appearing in usertask2..Plz help

Comment: @Seema How did you solve that? I have the same issue; Should be several minutes but actually executes almsot immediately.